# CUDA fails to detect graphics card

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have the problem that I get an error message

```
    Exception during execution: CUDA error: no CUDA-capable device is detected (src/cuda/lm/Cuda.cu:60)
```

Some information on the graphics card:

```
    $ lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 
    02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 680] [10de:1180] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. Device [19da:1255]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

and

```
    $ xrandr --prop 
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
    DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    BorderDimensions: 
    Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
    SignalFormat:   VGA
    supported: VGA         
    ConnectorType:  DVI-I
    ConnectorNumber: 0 (0x00000000)
_   ConnectorLocation: 0 (0x00000000)
    DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
EDID:
    00ffffffffffff000469942401010101
    0716010380351e78ea9265a655559f28
    0d5054bfef00714f818081409500a940
    b300d1c00101023a801871382d40582c
    4500132b2100001e000000fd00324c1e
    5311000a202020202020000000fc0056
    453234380a20202020202020000000ff
    0043324c4d51533037363031330a00d2
BorderDimensions: 
Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
SignalFormat:   TMDS
    supported: TMDS        
ConnectorType:  DVI-I
ConnectorNumber: 0 (0x00000000)
_ConnectorLocation: 0 (0x00000000)
       1920x1080      60.0*+
       1680x1050      60.0  
       1600x1200      60.0  
       1440x900       59.9  
       1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
       1280x960       60.0  
       1152x864       75.0  
       1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
       800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
       640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
    HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
       BorderDimensions: 
       Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
       SignalFormat:    TMDS
            supported: TMDS        
       ConnectorType:   HDMI
       ConnectorNumber: 2 (0x00000002)
        _ConnectorLocation: 2 (0x00000002)
    DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
         BorderDimensions: 
         Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
        SignalFormat:   TMDS
             supported: TMDS        
          ConnectorType:    DisplayPort
        ConnectorNumber: 3 (0x00000003)
        _ConnectorLocation: 3 (0x00000003)
    DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        BorderDimensions: 
        Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
        SignalFormat:   TMDS
            supported: TMDS        
        ConnectorType:  DVI-D
        ConnectorNumber: 1 (0x00000001)
        _ConnectorLocation: 1 (0x00000001)
       DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
           BorderDimensions: 
        Border: CARDINAL(6) (format 16 items 4) ????
         SignalFormat:  DisplayPort
             supported: DisplayPort 
         ConnectorType: DisplayPort
        ConnectorNumber: 3 (0x00000003)
        _ConnectorLocation: 3 (0x00000003)
```

a nvidia bugreport can be found on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3hwfjp5isooc6n/nvidia-bug-report.log.gz?dl=0) Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem please?

Kind regards,

David

Comment: What driver are you using? Try installing the proprietary driver sugegsted in Ubuntu's driver manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu 14.04 you can install nvidia-331, NVIDIA CUDA toolkit and the NVIDIA CUDA 5.5 Runtime library directly from the Ubuntu Software Center. libcudart5.5 is the package name of the NVIDIA CUDA runtime library. libcudart5.5 requires the nvidia-331 or more recent graphics driver. There is also an NVIDIA CUDA toolkit package (nvidia-cuda-toolkit) in the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, and like libcudart5.5 it is also version 5.5.

The three packages mentioned above are working on my Ubuntu 14.04 with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 graphics card. You could also install the nvidia-331-updates package instead of nvidia-331.

Comment: Hi Karel, thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on the computer. Do you know any other method that would help here other than upgrading the system?

Comment: You can download the Nvidia driver and CUDA packages from the Nvidia website. Starting in Ubuntu 14.04, all of the necessary packages for running CUDA are available from the Ubuntu Software Center. Since you already have Ubuntu 12.04, it is understandable that you would want to install the packages you want without upgrading. [CUDA 6.5 Production Release - Ubuntu 12.04](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1204/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1204_6.5-14_amd64.deb) & double-click to install it in the Ubuntu Software Center and it will resolve the package's dependencies for you.

Comment: Currently, the driver nvidia_current is installed. I tried to deactivate it in the system settings - additional drivers and then install the NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.62, which failed. I put the logfile on https://www.dropbox.com/s/am8ixwo150p998o/jockey.log?dl=0 maybe you know what to look for? I really appreciate your help so far, thanks.

Comment: From the terminal, the command `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` removes the existing Nvidia driver. Then when you reboot the computer, it will be using the default open source driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia driver. So now you can install a different Nvidia driver, if you want to.

Comment: I don't know whether it was from the remove command or a problem I caused but the driver was shot and the resolution reduced to almost four pixels ;) But a friend managed to set up the correct 331 driver and then one only had to install the package nvidia-331-uvm and all was fine. Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.