# Ubuntu freeze after successful cuda installation?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

On my fresh installed 14.04.2 ubuntu I have installed nvidia driver and cuda toolkit 7. After I installed I have restarted then added the cuda path variables and then ran deviceQuery and it is passed. but when I restart my notebook it freezes on splash screen. Do you know the reason for it? is any problem with 14.04 version of ubuntu?.

I have tried all other approaches like first install cuda driver and then tried to installed cuda toolkit. always i ended up with the black screen. Nothing worked worked for me.

Why I couldn't get this done on Ubuntu? I have mac and windows those are working fine. Could anyone help? I am trying for 2 days. always reinstall and installing cuda. :(

Laptop Lenovo Y50
GPU GTX960M.

Comment: NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 7 is very nice, but it is aggravating when it doesn't work properly. I suggest that you read this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/515926/cuda-fails-to-detect-graphics-card/515930#515930 which will solve your problem except that it does not install the latest version of NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit, which you may need, in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on a Zareason Verix laptop. The problem seems to be that NVIDIA drivers and the CUDA toolkit will not work on an Optimus computer with both Intel and NVIDIA chips. I've been a dozen rounds with support teams from both NVIDA and Zareason and the conclusion is that unless I am willing to modify the bios code I will not be able to use Theano and other such platforms. My stopgap solution is to use an AWS g2.2xlarge Instance which infuriates me but at least it does work.